# Button value set in editable div when click on

Tags: javascript, html

I am using button tag `<button value="1">1</button>`

Basically I want when this button is pressed, the value of the button is set into editable div.

`<div contentEditable='true'; >Value from button</div>`

Is that possible with client side script?

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uu5p9/

Comment: My plan to make calculator this is help full but i want some space between first and second and so on.

Comment: AS a side note to all answers below... suggesting to use `onclick` in 2013 should be a bannable offense :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code: (**EDIT** Modified as user has subsequently indicated that he will use this to create a calculator)

We are doing the following:

1. Assign an onclick function to the button. This will be called whenever the button is clicked.
2. An ID is added to both the `button` tag and the `div` tag to access them using the `getElementById` method in JavaScript.
3. `this.value` will pass the `value` of the `button` that is currently clicked to the function.
4. Inside the JavaScript, we get the value of the button and set it to the `innerHTML` of the required `div`. **Note:** Since `+=` is used, it would take the current contents of the `div` and append the button's value to it (like, if 1 is pressed followed by 2, the `div` would have 12 as its content).

**HTML**

```
<button value="1" id='btn1' onclick='setBtnValue(this.value);'>1</button>
<button value="2" id='btn2' onclick='setBtnValue(this.value);'>2</button>
<div contentEditable='true' id='div1'></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function setBtnValue(btnVal){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += btnVal;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/SBEM2/)

Comment: Thanks harry you save my time with batter explanation.

Comment: always glad to be of help mate :). Have a look at the `addEventListener` section in ZenMaster's answer also. That is another way of attaching a function to the button `click` event and will come in handy when you have a lot of such buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you can use getElementById method.

```
<button value="1" onclick="function1(this)">1</button>
<div contentEditable='true' id='edit'>value from button</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   function function1(obj){
      document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML=obj.value;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible but you have to assign the `id`.

```
<button onclick="put()" id="but" value="1">1</button>

<div id="pol" >Value from button</div>
```

Now with function use

```
function put()
{
document.getElementById("pol").innerHTML  = document.getElementById("but").value;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/Xquju/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button value="1" class="button">1</button>
<button value="2" class="button">2</button>
<div contentEditable="true" id="element"></div>
```

JS:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
var div = document.getElementById('element');

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        div.innerHTML = event.target.value;
    });
}
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/RddEc/)

Comment: thanks for quick response.I want some space between one and two because i want to make calculator.You know i want to use div as a calculator screen.